# Failed to Import MySql database from phpMyAdmin as well as Command line

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mysql, lamp, innodb

Well, I have tried to import small size database, it works. However, when I am about import a large database it shows the following error from phpMyadmin.

```
Static analysis:

1 errors were found during analysis.

    Missing expression. (near "ON" at position 25)

SQL query: Edit Edit

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = ON;

MySQL said: Documentation
#2006 - MySQL server has gone away
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmqwp.png)

and I have to log in again.
When I view log file from `/var/log/mysql/error.log`

```
2022-01-28T10:52:50.467847Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013183] 
[InnoDB] Assertion failure: ddl0builder.cc:1495:n >= IO_BLOCK_SIZE thread 140213208729344
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
10:52:50 UTC - mysqld got signal 6 ;
Most likely, you have hit a bug, but this error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
Thread pointer: 0x0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 0 thread_stack 0x100000
2022-01-28T10:52:50.471914Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013183] 
[InnoDB] Assertion failure: ddl0buffer.cc:204:ptr < bounds.second thread 140213217122048
```

And when I try with command line to import database it shows following err
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GwAkf.png)

```
lochan@lochan-Inspiron-5593:~$ mysql -u root -p wp_test < ~/Downloads/wp_ndw_staging.sql
Enter password: 
ERROR 2013 (HY000) at line 3429: Lost connection to MySQL server during query
```

My paramter in `php.ini` are as follow

```
post_max_size = 1500M
upload_max_filesize = 1500M
```

I have tried to place recovery parameter in `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`

```
[mysqld]
innodb_force_recovery = 1
```

and I tried following in `mysqld.cnf` file but it didn't work.

```
key_buffer_size = 1600M
max_allowed_packet  = 6400M
```

Comment: What were the few lines just before that one?  How much RAM do you have?  THose settings are probably excessive.

Comment: This really looks like a stack over- or underflow. So, like a bug in the code.... What version are you using (originally and now?) How big was the database you wanted to import?

Answer (score 0):

I backed up all my database and just uninstalled SQL Server and all the packages related to SQL Server and reinstalled them and it works just fine.